# adding labels to points in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

```
Table[{Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]}, {t, 0, 6}]
ListPlot[%]
```

This code plots 6 points in the complex plane. To each point I would like to add a label in the plot that lists the value of `t`. How can I do that?

Please note:
I want to print this plot, so the labels should all be visible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All plotting functions are just wrappers for `Graphics` objects. `Show` can be used to combine these objects, and that's one way of doing what you want here.

Take the following code as a starting point; you will of course have to tweak the positions of the labels (right now it's just a radial factor that offsets them). Note that I modified the `data` variable so that it includes $t$; it is now of the form `{t, Re, Im}`. The `ListPlot` will plot only the real and imaginary parts (`data[[All, {2, 3}]]`), while the `Text` passage also takes into account the value of $t$.

```
data = Table[{t, Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]}, {t, 0, 6}];
dataPlot = ListPlot[data[[All, {2, 3}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large];
labels = Text[#[[1]], 1.1 #[[{2, 3}]]] & /@ data;
Show[
    dataPlot,
    Graphics[{Red, labels}],
    PlotRange -> 6 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

> [image]

You can of course generalize this arbitrarily, e.g. color the labels differently, change font size etc. I kept the above to a minimum to avoid cluttering, the rest is up to you.

Comment: Why don't you use an offset for Text?

Comment: I felt like a factor fits the radial symmetry nicer here, but you're of course not limited to that.

Comment: I think, this does not behave well: data = Table[{t, Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]} + 20, {t, 0, 
    6}];
dataPlot = 
  ListPlot[data[[All, {2, 3}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large];
labels = Text[#[[1]], 1.1 #[[{2, 3}]]] & /@ data;
Show[dataPlot, Graphics[{Red, labels}], AspectRatio -> 1]

Comment: Well you just added 20 to all imaginary parts. If you want a text offset, you'll have to change the `1.1 #[[{2, 3}]]` to something like `#[[{2, 3}]]+{1,1}`.

Comment: The point is that with the third argument to Text you do not have to change anything.

Comment: Except for the third argument. Which is limited to additive offsets.

Comment: I am using this but when there are two points on the same position the labels show on top of each other. I have tried using tally and then position to try to add an offset to each label for a point that is in the same location as another but I can't get Position to work in this instance.

Answer (score 24):

Just discovered this thread while looking for an answer to the same question and figured I probably couldn't help the OP now, but decided to provide the answer I found for posterity.

You could wrap each point you're plotting in the `Labeled` function like so:

```
Table[
  Labeled[
    {Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]},
    t
  ]
  , {t, 0, 6}];
ListPlot[%]
```

`Labeled` has options to control placement and whatnot. All in the documentation.

Comment: This code does not work...

Comment: @geordie It does for me on 9.0.1. You probably are using an old version... not really the OP's fault or downvote worthy, imo.

Comment: Fair enough. Apologies to the OP.

Comment: How would I alter that if my data set were a list of pairs and I didnt have to use Table ? eg data={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} and labels={a,b,c}.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
data = Table[
  Tooltip[{Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]}, t], {t, 0, 6}]
ListPlot[data]
```

A little bit of a hack...

```
data = Table[{coord = {Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]}, 
   Text[t, coord, {-2, 0}]}, {t, 0, 6}]
Show[ListPlot[data[[All, 1]]], Graphics[data[[All, 2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]