# Applying a function to list of points and plot the results in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

Assume there are three groups of 2-dimensional coordinates

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, .25], {15, 2}] & /@ Range[3];
```

Is there a way to `ListPlot` these data points just like

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image]

but instead of the dots with the result of an integer-valued function, e.g. `Round[Norm[#]]&`, shown in the according colour?

I already had a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/listplot-with-plotmarkers-determined-by-point) and [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/adding-labels-to-points-in-listplot) question, but wasn't able to modify the answers to obtain the desired result.

Comment: you want numbers instead of the points?

Comment: Yes, each point should be the number resulting in applying to it a pre-defined function f:R^2 -> N in the colour as shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but you could do something like

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}] /. 
   {Point[a_] :> (Text[Round[Norm[#]], #] & /@ a)}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think there was a question by Mr.W in SO showing that the points aren't shown in their correct positions with this technique. If my memory does not fail, the trick was rasterizing the symbols before plotting. Mmm ... I should check

Comment: @Verde I missed that question. If I superpose the original `ListPlot` on top of the one above, the numbers seem to be shifted slightly with respect to the dots by a few pixels. I wonder what causes this.

Comment: @Verde [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/5) is probably the question you're thinking of...

Answer (score 7):

The numbers will confusingly overlap, especially with more precision shown. Just in case here is a solution with radius of disk reflecting the `Norm` and `Tooltip` showing the number?

```
Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[], 1, 1, .4], 
    Map[Tooltip[Disk[#, .02 Norm[#]], Norm[#]] &, #]} & /@ data, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, .25], {15, 2}] & /@ Range[3];

ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
```

[image]

```
data2 = Flatten[data, {2, 1}];
(* or data2 = Join @@ Transpose[data] *)

ListPlot[List /@ data2,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}, 
 PlotMarkers -> (Round[Norm @ #] & /@ data2)]
```

[image]