# Positioning Labeled points in ListPlot gives unexpected results and errors

Tags: plotting, graphics

Original question can be seen in the edit history....

#### Update

A [simpler example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/adding-labels-to-points-in-listplot) - same problem.

```
i = 
  Table[
    Labeled[{Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]},t, {Right, Top}], 
    {t, 0, 6}]
```

> ```
> {Labeled[{5, 0}, 0, {Right, Top}], 
>  Labeled[{5*Cos[5/2], 5*Sin[5/2]}, 1, {Right, Top}], 
>  Labeled[{5*Cos[5], 5*Sin[5]}, 2, {Right, Top}], 
>  Labeled[{5*Cos[15/2], 5*Sin[15/2]}, 3, {Right, Top}], 
>  Labeled[{5*Cos[10], 5*Sin[10]}, 4, {Right, Top}], 
>  Labeled[{5*Cos[25/2], 5*Sin[25/2]}, 5, {Right, Top}], 
>  Labeled[{5*Cos[15], 5*Sin[15]}, 6, {Right, Top}]}
> ```

```
ListPlot[i]
```

[image]

Without `PlotMarkers` as an option, it will not work.

```
ListPlot[i, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}]
```

[image]

With `PlotMarkers` it works but the labels are offset to the reverse of the specified coordinates. Is this not unusual behaviour?

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I'm running

[image]

Comment: Please do not use [bug] untill it is confirmend. Also, I can't find it so could you tell me why you think `ListPlot` will accept `Labeled` coordinates?

Comment: no labels at all here (version 9.0.1, Mac OS X)

Comment: Your example code is so far from a minimum working example that it obscures your problem rather than elucidating it.

Comment: @Kuba. Is there somewhere where I can find out useful hints like "... never say bug ..." - it says nothing about this in the mmaSE help pages. I found the reference to using `Labeled` within `ListPlot` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/adding-labels-to-points-in-listplot). That answer was upvoted 9 times but it won't evaluate! Also,see update. Thanks.

Comment: @geordie When you choose the "bugs" tag, a popup appears (you can also hover on the tag) saying: _"This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions."_

Comment: @rm-rf  Ok, Thanks for the clarification. So, is it a (possibly version specific) bug?

Comment: @geordie I wouldn't necessarily call it a bug... there is really no reason to expect that `ListPlot` will automatically handle labeled points, so I would be more inclined to believe that this functionality was added in v9.  On the other hand, if you can reproduce the plot in v6, v7, v9 but not v8, then you might consider it a version specific bug.

Comment: still no labels at all for me :( (version 9.0.1, Mac OS X)

Comment: workaround - `BubbleChart[i, ChartElementFunction -> ({Disk[Most[#2], .3], White, Text[Last[#2], Most[#2]]} & ), Axes -> True, Frame -> False]` :)

Answer (score 3):

In V.10.4.1, `ListPlot` works as expected when given the OP's data.

```
i = 
  Table[Labeled[{Re[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]], Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]}, t, {Right}], {t, 0, 6}];
ListPlot[i]
```

[image: plot]

So what the OP experienced appears to be a bug that has been fixed.