# Labels on 2D ListPlot Markers

Tags: plotting, labeling, style, marker

If we take the example

```
ListPlot[{{1.5, 2}, {1, -2}, {2.5, 6}, {3, -5}} -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}]
```

I would to see the labels correctly correspond to the 2D points, but unfortunately this does not happen. What should I do to obtain this?

Comment: This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzBiN.png. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I have Mathematica 10. That's not what I see. I don't see any labels at all.

Comment: Callout is new in 11. For earlier versions you need to use something like: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1857/5478 seems to work well: `ListPlot[MapThread[
  Labeled, {{{1.5, 2}, {1, -2}, {2.5, 6}, {3, -5}}, {"a", "b", "c", 
    "d"}}]]`