# Labelling on ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

Is it possible to add to the `Mesh` points in a `ParametricPlot` the x-values in sort of a `Callout`-style way? E.g. on the following simple function:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin@x, .3 Log@(x^2)}, {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> 20]
```

The points are on the plot (a little small), now there should be the x values (0,0.5,1,1.5,...) indicated next to the points, as said in form of as it is produced with `Callout`.

Comment: This might help: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/adding-labels-to-points-in-listplot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{Sin@x, .3 Log@(x^2)}, {x, 0, 10}, 
   Mesh -> {Subdivide[0, 10, 20]}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]];
points = Cases[Normal[pp], Point[x_] :> x, ∞];
Show[pp, ListPlot[Callout[#, #2] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{SortBy[points, Last], N @ Rest@Subdivide[0, 10, 20]}]], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Also

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin@x, .3 Log@(x^2)}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> ListPlot[Callout[{##2}, #] & @@@ 
   Table[N@{x, Sin@x, .3 Log @ (x^2)}, {x, Subdivide[0, 10, 20]}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]][[1]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin@x, .3 Log@(x^2)}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4], 
    {Text[N[#], pt = {Sin@#, .3 Log@(#^2)}, {0, If[IntegerQ[#], -2, 2]}], 
      Red, Point[pt]} & /@ Range[1/2, 10, 1/2]}]
```

[image]